# SPSS and SharePoint 2010 Crawl Index

Tags: crawling

I have a folder on my desktop that I created and SharePoint 2010 crawl that folder.
I have Excel, Word, and .sav (SPSS) files in there. After I was done crawling, I was able to search the folder fine, except it didn't let me find any of my .sav files in there?
Does this mean SharePoint 2010 does NOT crawl spss files (.sav) or is there something I need to change in Central Admin?

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box SharePoint will not be able to crawl the contents of these files. I would check 2 things. First, make sure the file type is in the allowed file types to make sure that the results will be available. Second, if you want to be able to search by contents, you will need to have an iFilter for these file types. Then SharePoint will be able to crack it open and index the contents.

Answer (score 3):

In Search configuration in Central Administration, make sure you have added .sav to the "File Types" to include in crawls (left-hand column, under "Crawling").

You may also need an iFilter to enable search to crack open the files, depending on their format.

Comment: Yes, what SPDoctor said, he was just slightly faster on the answer.

Comment: Not by much....